# Is this a big bug in the implementation of tolower in ntoskrnl.exe?

Tags: c++, c, windows, kernel, driver

The following code works fine in user mode:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    //
    // 0x7f51 is the unicode code of Chinese character '网'
    //
    int n = tolower(0x7f51); // n will equal 0x7f51
}
```

However, if we are in kernel mode, `n` will equal `0x7f71` !!!

The simplest sample code:

```
#include <ntifs.h>

ULONG NTAPI DriverEntry(PDRIVER_OBJECT, PUNICODE_STRING)
{
    int n = tolower(0x7f51); // n will equal 0x7f71 !!!

    return 0;
}
```

Is this a big bug in the implementation of `tolower` in ntoskrnl.exe?

Comment: I think it just means that you have different locale settings in kernel mode. Try using `tolower_l()` instead.

Comment: That looks like it's just doing ASCII lowercasing on the lowest 7 bits: 0x51 -> 0x71.

Comment: `tolower()` cannot work with unicode. It uses current locale for finding corresponding lowercase letter. C99 has `towlower()`, it probably can help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`tolower(int c)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/tolower.html) is defined only for integers `c`, that are EOF or representable as an unsigned char. `0x7f51` is neither. Therefore, the behaviour of `tolower(0x7f51)` is undefined.

Comment: Hmm. Wonder if there are implementations where `char` is 16+ bits and have implemented `tolower()`?  Certainly not common.

Answer (score 1):

tolower() is designed for ANSI characters, not for Unicode.
C program's locale setting affects its behavior.
It's better to use Windows specific conversion functions in NT kernel.